# Do I really need to provide a long list of documents when applying for a German Schengen visa for the purpose of attending an interview?

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas

I have been invited  to Germany (all expenses and medical insurance covered ) for a F2F interview. The prospective employer has sent me an invitation letter stating the purpose. The documents checklist for Schengen business Visa asks for the the company incorporation letter, ITR Forms etc. As the trip is only for 2 days, and since I am going only for a job interview, are those documents really required? 
I am ready with the application form, last 3 months bank statement, current employment contract and payslips. The German company is sending me the flight tickets and accommodation particulars by today.

I need to be in Germany by 10th February. Can someone pls guide me?

Comment: The company should stand ready to help with this. If the company is capable (logistically, legally) of hiring workers from outside the EU them they must be capable of providing you with everything you need to get the visa. If they can't do the paperwork for the visit then they won't manage the employment visa either.

Comment: Well, if we say these documetns are not required, what will you do? Not provide them?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies...I have already sent the request to the company asking for the documents listed in the checklist but haven't heard back from them. Since, I have to be in Germany by 10th, and visa appointment slots are available for next week, I am concerned about not getting the visa on time...I guess I need to push them to send me the documents and just hope that I get through.

Comment: What checklist are you using?

Comment: Depending on where you come from (what country) it might be worth checking if you can use a tourist visum. I don't think that having a job interview would violate the rules.

Comment: @phoog, I am using the checklist from the vfs Germany India site. ://www.vfs-germany.co.in/newdelhi_northindia/business_docreq.html. TorstenS, I am traveling from India and have to apply for Schengen Business visa - confirmed with the embassy today.

Comment: @TorstenS, Mathangi: there's no such thing as a Schengen tourist visa or business visa; both tourists and business visitors are issued "short-stay" visas, which are type C visas.  There are several possible travel purposes for such visas, of which two are tourism and business.  The documents that should be submitted to justify the purpose of travel do depend on the purpose, of course.

Comment: Just to clarify: There is a number of countries which residents are allowed to visit Germany / the Schengen area without having to apply for a visum upfront. Unfortunately, this isn't the case for India.

Comment: VTC: OP had official confirmation from the Consulate what was required, and any response here would merely be opinions/suggestions, unwise and potentially risky, IMHO. OP has not returned to TSE in 6 months.